# Auto reload spring boot application in docker when using spring-security

Tags: spring, docker

I am developing an application with spring boot 2.
I deployed the application in docker, and I activated the "auto reload in docker with spring devtools"
but after adding spring-security, the autoreload does not work anymore.
I'm getting an error when the auto restart is triggered:

```
Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected 302 FOUND response uploading class files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security is likely intercepting the HTTP requests that the autoreload system is using and redirecting you to the login page. You'll need to figure out what URLs the system uses and set those to `permitAll()` in the development environment.

Comment: Exactly ! the URL used is : 
Listening for remote restart updates on **/.~~spring-boot!~/restart**